# how to save output file in multiple threading

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, networking

I am writing a script in Fortinet device configuration, we are using in the thread but at the time we had can't save in the output file. we use 'a' and 'a+'.

**Our Code**

```
    output = net_connect.send_config_from_file(config_file='Cmd_File')
    print("{}: Printing output...".format(i))
    Save_File = open("Config", 'a')
    print('\n********************* '.format(i, ip) + '*' * 50)
    Save_File.write(output)
    time.sleep(3)
    print(output)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't save in the output file"? Does ``Save_File.write(output)`` produce an error? Is the file empty? Are you aware that file writes are buffered and may not be immediately visible to other processes?

Comment: Its file is empty only.